# I would like to add a dynamic component

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to add a dynamic component from a service.
My component is BubbleComponent.

```
import { BubbleComponent } from '@app/component/bubble';
import {SiplecService} from '@app/service/siplec.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutes),
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent, BasketComponent, BubbleComponent],
  entryComponents: [ BubbleComponent ],
  providers: [ SiplecService ]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

In my service:

```
 setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef: any) {
        this.rootViewContainer = viewContainerRef;
    }
    addDynamicComponent() {
        const factory = this.factoryResolver
            .resolveComponentFactory(BubbleComponent);
        const component = factory
            .create(this.rootViewContainer.parentInjector);
        this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView);
    }
```

I get the following error :

> ERROR Error: No component factory found for BubbleComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
>       at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:7409)

Comment: Is `addDynamicComponent` in your `SiplecService` service?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below of code to see if it work

```
@ViewChild("dynamicContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
componentRef: ComponentRef<BubbleComponent>;
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

createComponent(type) {
    //Clear the container.
    this.container.clear();
    //Create a factory for component.
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BubbleComponent);
    //Create a component using the factory
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

Also make sure you import into declarations too

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BubbleComponent
  ],
```

Comment: You can view the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)